# how to remove rows of missing cases in a whole data frame when some columns of the data frame have list elements?

Tags: r

Currently "complete.cases" or "na.omit" does not work if some columns of the data frame have list elements.

> Error output: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid subscript type
>   'list'

Comment: Why are there lists in your data.frame? That seems like a bad idea. It will surely break many things. You should at least provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we know what your data looks like. What counts as missing in columns that have lists?

Comment: @MrFlick I tend to agree, but list inside data frames has [at least one influential advocate](https://blog.rstudio.org/author/hadleywickham/) (just find `purrr` on that page for examples).

Comment: Well then I guess we have to wait till Hadley releases the `complete_cases` package

Comment: `list` objects in `data.frames` are unusual, but perfectly valid structures. It is an interesting question imo, as dealing with something like `dat <- data.frame(a=c(NA,2,3), b=I(list(1:2, NA, 3:4)))` is not straightforward.

Comment: @thelatemail - thank you for the reproducible example. I have a similar problem. unable to use complete.cases(dat)

Comment: Which begs the question of OP: do you want to check the lists for missing values at the top level (or deeper?) or are you content just checking the non-list columns?

Comment: @Gregor - good point - `dat <- data.frame(a=c(NA,2,3), b=I(list(1:2, c(1,NA), 3:4)))` might be an example of a more complex data.frame.

Comment: Also, OP, if `na.omit` isn't working for you you may need your own reproducible example: `na.omit(dat)` works just fine using thelatemail's `dat` (by ignoring the list column). A look at `stats:::na.omit.data.frame` show that it passes non-atomic columns: `if (!is.atomic(x)); next`.

Comment: Yes, na.omit works for me but not complete.cases! I dont have any NAs inside the list, so that is not a problem. thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case please edit your question where you state "*...`na.omit` does not work*".

Comment: na.omit still does not remove NA's when inside the list... so the question holds if NA's are inside the list. so i guess the questions holds in general